# How to take advantage of custom events in Live Agent?

Tags: liveagent, custom

I found that you can send, receive, and monitor custom events in Live Agent. This seems like it could have great applications, but I'm not sure what it could be used for. Does anyone have examples of how to use custom events to enhance the customer/agent experience?

liveagent.chasitor.getCustomEvents()
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_chasitor_getCustomEvents.htm